# Subclass UIApplication with Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

In Objective C it was simple: it was sufficient to update the main.m file and change the UIApplicationMain() parameters

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([CustomUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

But in swift there is no main.m file, since the guide says

“Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program, so you don’t need a main function.”

So, how to subclass UIApplication in swift?? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why would it be preferrable to change `UIApplicationMain()` parameters, to adding the class name under `NSPrincipalClass` in the app-info.plist?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

> **NOTE** the syntax has been updated for XCode 10.1 and Swift 5 in Jun 2019 ( credits to [matt's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088928/xcode-8-beta-6-main-swift-wont-compile/39089634#39089634) && [Tung Fam's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift/56528441#56528441) ), if you are looking for the previous syntaxes look at the edit section.

Ok, I've found the solution

First, I've noticed that, at the top of the AppDelegate.swift file, there is this line

```
@UIApplicationMain
```

Since this line is outside any scope (it's at file level), it's executed immediately, and I assume that the compiler translate it in a standard main function.

So, I did this, starting from a new Swift-Only application:

- commented out `@UIApplicationMain`
- added a main.swift file like this (FLApplication is my subclass).
  **IMPORTANT** the file MUST BE NAMED main.swift, since top level statements are not supported on other files! You can't add the UIApplicationMain() call inside any other file, otherwise you'll receive this error:

> Expressions are not allowed at the top level

This is the main.swift file

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, 
    NSStringFromClass(FLApplication.self), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Then, create a swift file for the UIApplication subclass, FLApplication.swift, with this code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class FLApplication: UIApplication {
    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        super.sendEvent(event)
        print("send event")
    }
}
```

now, UIApplication is correctly subclassed and you'll see the "send event" messages in the log

---

> **OLD EDITS**
>   For reference, since this has changed a lot from version 1 to version 3, I leave here all the previous edits

---

**EDIT - MARCH 2015**

As commented by Hu Junfeng now the explanations about `UIApplicationMain` and the main.swift file are documented in the Attributes section of The Swift Language Reference: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

As commented by Thomas Verbeek
 In the XCode 6.3 Beta, you might find that C_ARGC and C_ARGV have been renamed to Process.argc and Process.unsafeArgv respectively. Your UIApplicationMain call in the main.swift file will need updating to:

```
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(FLApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

The pre-XCode 8 syntax was

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, NSStringFromClass(FLApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

---

**EDIT - DEC 2016**

Solution for Xcode 8, before beta 6

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory( 
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, 
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    NSStringFromClass(FLApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand if it's possible to call UIApplicationMain() directly in the AppDelegate.swift file, since it seems that there is a "swift version" of this method, but I have a compiler error, I'll do some tests searching for a "swift only" solution

Comment: Incredibly cool. I'm curious as to what the use-case is for overriding `sendEvent:` nowadays (I remember having to do it in iOS 3...)

Comment: In case someone wants to know, `UIApplicationMain` and `main.swift` are documented in the Attributes section of The Swift Language Reference. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm 99% sure that in the first release of the Swift manual it wasn't documented :-) however I'll update the answer adding your informations.

Comment: Great answer. In the XCode 6.3 Beta, you might find that `C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV` have been renamed to `Process.argc` and `Process.unsafeArgv` respectively. Your UIApplicationMain call in the main.swift file will need updating to `UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(KBApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))`

Comment: In addition to @hujunfeng, `main.swift` is explained in Files and Initialization https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7

Comment: Latest version of calling UIApplicationMain can be found here for Swift 3. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39089634/590864

Comment: @suleymancalik thanks, I updated the answer adding the credits to the answer you linked

Comment: @LombaX In main.swift, `UIApplicationMain()` returns an `Int32`. Therefore, shouldn't it be wrapped in an `exit()` call so the process can report its exit status back to the OS? Like `exit(UIApplicationMain(...))`

Comment: @LombaX Never mind my previous comment about using `exit()`. The documentation for `UIApplicationMain()` says the "function never returns. When users exit an iOS app ... the app moves to the background." Therefore, it seems iOS is "wrapping" the launched iOS app process, and ignoring whatever exit code the process _would_ terminate with.

Comment: in Xcode 10 those first two arguments would be `CommandLine.argc` and `CommandLine.unsafeArgv`

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is to extend `UIApplication` instead of subclassing it. According to the [iBook](https://itun.es/br/jEUH0.l) released by Apple, extensions in Swift can:

> Add computed properties and computed static properties 
>   Define instance methods and type methods 
>   Provide new initializers
>   Define subscripts
>   Define and use new nested types Make an existing type conform to a protocol
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.

If your needs in subclassing `UIApplication` are satisfied by those capabilities, an Extension might be the way to go.

Comment: nice advice - not answer imho :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Subclass UIApplication**

1. Create a subclass of `UIApplication` and add your logic

   ```
   import UIKit

   class CustomUIApplication: UIApplication {
       override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
           super.sendEvent(event)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a `main.swift` file that calls the `UIApplicationMain()` global function[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988242/4770877), which is the new entry point of your application that is called by the OS. This function receives argument from called function, `UIApplication` class name, `UIApplicationDelegate` class name and starts the main RunLoop[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75204210/4770877).

   ```
   import UIKit

   UIApplicationMain(
       CommandLine.argc,
       CommandLine.unsafeArgv,

       NSStringFromClass(CustomUIApplication.self), //was created at step 1
       NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
   )
   ```
3. Remove/comment the `@UIApplicationMain` annotation on the default `AppDelegate`.

`@UIApplicationMain` generates `main.swift`.

If you don't you will get a compile error:

> `UIApplicationMain` attribute cannot be used in a module that contains top-level code

```
//@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    //...
}
```