# What does "@UIApplicationMain" mean?

Tags: swift

I just created my first Swift project, in the `AppDelegate.swift` there is a line above a class declaration - why is it there?!

```
...
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain // <- WHY IS IT HERE?
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
...
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The `@UIApplicationMain` attribute in Swift replaces the trivial `main.m` file found in Objective-C projects (whose purpose is to implement the `main` function that's the entry point for all C programs and call `UIApplicationMain` to kick off the Cocoa Touch run loop and app infrastructure).

In Objective-C, the main (heh) bit of per-app configuration that the `UIApplicationMain` function provides is designating one of your app's custom classes as the delegate of the shared `UIApplication` object. In Swift, you can easily designate this class by adding [the `@UIApplicationMain` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) to that class' declaration. (You can also still invoke the `UIApplicationMain` function directly if you have reason to. In Swift you put that call in top-level code in a `main.swift` file.)

`@UIApplicationMain` is for iOS only. In OS X, the app delegate is traditionally set in the main nib file designated by the Info.plist (the same for Swift as for ObjC) — but with OS X storyboards there's no main nib file, so `@NSApplicationMain` does the same thing there.

Comment: On page 58 in The Swift Programming Language I found the Attributes section, interesting.

Comment: I'd have quoted the docs in my answer, but there don't seem to be any for this attribute just yet. The [Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) page you found is where you probably *would* find it.

Comment: A description for `UIApplicationMain` is there now. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Comment: Re your last sentence, note that OS X has the equivalent @NSApplicationMain

Comment: @UIApplicationMain is also for tvOS

Comment: Explanation about the difference between `@UIApplicationMain` and `@main`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429098/what-is-the-differnce-between-main-and-uiapplicationmain

Answer (score 7):

@UIApplicationMain attribute is a replacement of main.m file & and entry point for your application to start.

One more thing your program can work without this @UIApplicationMain all you need to do is  comment //@UIApplicationMain`
create main.swift same as main.m in objective c and write below code.
that will be the entry point of your application

```
import Foundation
class FLApplication: UIApplication
{
    override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent!)
    {
        println("Entry Point") // this is an example
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that, it compiles and runs, but finished after installing the app and sendEvent is never called. So what? :)

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift — but again I don't land in sendEvent...

Comment: @StuFFmc thank for this info. sendEvent method not called for me too.

Comment: The `Foundation` import, the `FLApplication`, the random subclassing without declaring any using of the subclass... Sorry, but none of this answer makes sense except for the first sentence.

Answer (score 7):

The **AppDelegate.swift** source file has two primary functions:

- It creates the entry point to your app and a run loop that delivers
  input events to your app. This work is done by the ***UIApplicationMain***
  attribute **(@UIApplicationMain)**, which appears toward the top of the
  file. UIApplicationMain creates an application object that’s
  responsible for managing the life cycle of the app and an app
  delegate object.
- It defines the *AppDelegate* class, the blueprint for the app delegate object. The app delegate creates the window where your app’s content is drawn and provides a place to respond to state transitions within the app. The AppDelegate class is where you write your custom app-level code.

Comment: Hey @Manju....... I have overridden my UIApplication main as TimerUiApplication.............I have a variable in it..........How do i modify that variable of my UIApplication from my uiViewController.....................

Answer (score 5):

Now that the Swift documentation is updated, here is the relevant passage:

> **NSApplicationMain**
>
> Apply this attribute to a class to indicate that it is the application delegate. Using this attribute is equivalent to calling the NSApplicationMain(*:*:) function and passing this class’s name as the name of the delegate class.
>
> If you do not use this attribute, supply a main.swift file with a main() function that calls the NSApplicationMain(*:*:) function. For example, if your app uses a custom subclass of NSApplication as its principal class, call the NSApplicationMain function instead of using this attribute.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

**@UIApplicationMain** is an attribute applied to the class -declared below-  **AppDelegate**, to provide more information about this class.

In this case, the attribute **@UIApplicationMain** indicates that the class **AppDelegate** is the application delegate of your app.

Answer (score 0):

**UIApplicationMain**
Apply this attribute to a class to indicate that it is the application delegate. Using this attribute is equivalent to calling the UIApplicationMain function and passing this class’s name as the name of the delegate class.
[(Source)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)