# Swift: Undefined Symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, undefined

Im working with xcode6. My last memory was I've remove all swift file in my project and add it again, and I encountered this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`@UIApplicationMain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24516329/3804019) attribute to `AppDelegate`. or you forgot to add AppDelegate?

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    ...
}
```