# What Has Replaced the "main.m" File in Xcode 6.3

Tags: swift, appdelegate, xcode6.3

According to the IOS Developer Library at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html

**The main function in main.m calls the UIApplicationMain function within an autorelease pool.**

However, in XCode 6.3 it appears that there is no longer a "main.m" file. **What has replaced the "main.m" file?**

Thanks.

Comment: See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30081440/341994

Answer (score 5):

Your tags indicate that you use Swift, not Objective-C. Swift uses different mechanisms to start up your program. In general, it does not need a `main` function, since it is legal to write code that is not contained in a function.

The Swift project template [tags the `NSApplicationDelegate` implementation with `@NSApplicationMain` (or `@UIApplicationMain` on iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469639/251153). This tells the compiler to generate a `main` function which calls `NSApplicationMain`.