# I don't know where is a starting point in swift program

Tags: swift

I'm a beginner for swift. I knew that Swift is processed in order but program has a starting point and I think it is not Viewcontroller.swift in xcodeproj.
Where is the starting point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean

Answer (score 4):

All applications, whether it is Swift or Objetive C, starts with ***main*** class. But swift has auto implementation of main generated by `@UIApplicationMain` attributes. The simple implemetation of `@UIApplicationMain` would be like:

```
UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

which indicates to run the `AppDelegate` class.

Let's comment out `@UIApplicationMain` from `AppDelegate` and run. You will get build fail with two errors, like

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

See, it does need a main as entry/start point.

Now create a ***main.swift*** file and write the following code and run again.

```
import UIKit
UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

It will compile successfully and will load the view which is exactly same as `@UIApplicationMain` does.