# Where does a Swift iOS application begin its life?

Tags: ios, swift, program-entry-point, lifecycle

If I create an Objective-C iOS application in Xcode, a file named `main.m` is generated.  The contents of the file look something like this:

#### main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

And this is where an Objective-C iOS application begins its life.

Importantly, if I want to subclass `UIApplication` (for whatever reason), then *here* is where I go to tell my app which class to use for the application class.  Likewise, if for some reason I want to use a class name other than `AppDelegate` for my app, I'd change that information here.

**HOWEVER**, if I create a Swift iOS application in Xcode, no such file is generated (that I've been able to find).  Where do I set these things up at?

Comment: Not a duplicate in the strict sense, but you should find it all here: [What does “@UIApplicationMain” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean).

Answer (score 8):

In Swift you can use the `@UIApplicationMain` attribute on your app delegate class, and it will automatically call the `UIApplicationMain()` function for you.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class YourAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { ...
```

There's another option too:

> If you do not use this attribute, supply a main.swift file with a `main` function that calls the `UIApplicationMain` function. For example, if your app uses a custom subclass of `UIApplication` as its principal class, call the `UIApplicationMain` function instead of using this attribute.

---

**References:**

- [The Swift Programming Language: Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)
- [What does "@UIApplicationMain" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean)