# Swift OSX what is the first method to be run?

Tags: swift, macos

This seems like a newbie question but I've been struggling with it for a while now. I have some code initialisation that I'd like to run before my app launches.

At the moment I have set up my AppDelegate as follows:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification)
    {
        runMyInitCode()
    }
}
```

My problem is that all my object code runs before this. Where is the best place to call initialisation methods before anything else runs?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722672/where-does-a-swift-ios-application-begin-its-life.

Comment: Thanks. I have a useful global variable var app = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate. If I try to access this in override init() then it isn't initialised. If I try to initialise in init() I get errors. Where is the best place to initialise it?

Comment: `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate` is identical to `class AppDelegate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 4 options (in order of appearance):

- Override `init()`
- Override `awakeFromNib()`
- Delegate notification `applicationWillFinishLaunching`
- Delegate notification `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

The *best place* depends on your needs.

- If `IBOutlets` are involved put it not before `awakeFromNib`.
- If you are using a view based table view don't put it in `awakeFromNib` because it could be called multiple times.
- Registering `NSUserDefaults` can be put everywhere.
- Consider also lazy initialization.
- Consider also Cocoa Bindings.