# Is there any life-cycle graph for Swift look like same as we know for Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, lifecycle

We know iOS life-Cycle as below Graph with Objective-C:

[image]

e.g. where is main() in Swift project , or where is AppDelegate.swift's functions?

Comment: What do you mean by *"where is AppDelegate.swift functions?"*? `AppDelegate.swift` contains the `UIApplicationDelegate` methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does a Swift iOS application begin its life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722672/where-does-a-swift-ios-application-begin-its-life)

Comment: You will find more on this: [What does “@UIApplicationMain” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24516250/3687801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's the same because it's not a language depending life-cycle. It's an Application life-cycle.**

You could change the language, but the way application works still be the same. If there were any differences, you won't be able to use swift/objc in the same project.

All calls are still there, but they change the way they look (but not named) a bit because of swift syntax. You could look them up here: [Looking to understand the iOS UIViewController lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562938/looking-to-understand-the-ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle)