# I don't understand two fields in an App delegate class

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning iOS development and the following code is from the book *Programming iOS8 by Matt Neuberg.* It is an app delegate class to create a window. I do not understand -

1. In the second line what is `@UIApplicationMain` and why is it there? Is it a declaration of a global varibale?
2. What is the purpose of the parameter `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?`? I don't see it used anywhere in the function body.

```
import UIKIT
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate : UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window : UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

            self.window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            return true
    }
}
```

Comment: you can read more about the [Application's Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html) on Apple's site, maybe.

Comment: Thanks! That's a great resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `@UIApplicationMain` attribute in Swift replaces the trivial
>   `main.m` file found in Objective-C projects (whose purpose is to
>   implement the main function that's the entry point for all C programs
>   and call `UIApplicationMain` to kick off the Cocoa Touch run loop and
>   app infrastructure).
>
> In Objective-C, the `main` (heh) bit of per-app configuration that the
>   `UIApplicationMain` function provides is designating one of your app's
>   custom classes as the `delegate` of the shared `UIApplication` object.
>   In Swift, you can easily designate this class by adding the
>   `@UIApplicationMain` attribute to that class' declaration. (You can
>   also still invoke the `UIApplicationMain` function directly if you
>   have reason to. In Swift you put that call in top-level code in a
>   `main.swift` file.)
>
> `@UIApplicationMain` is for iOS only. In OS X, the app delegate is
>   traditionally set in the main nib file designated by the `Info.plist`
>   (the same for Swift as for ObjC) — but with OS X storyboards there's
>   no main nib file, so `@NSApplicationMain` does the same thing there.

Reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean).

And for your second point `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

Every app begins with `UIApplicationDelegate` -`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (or more accurately, -`application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, when implemented). It is called by the application to notify its delegate that the launch process is finishing, and nearly ready to run.