# Can 'downcasting' to AppDelegate ever fail?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

When working with CoreData, we need access to the shared store which is available via the AppDelegate. To obtain a reference to the AppDelegate we can get it by doing the following:

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate 
else {
        return
    }
```

Why do we have to be so safe when downcasting to the Appdelegate? Can the downcast ever fail for some reason and if so, why?

I have looked around and can't find a reason as to why we write this code, and wanting to know why I write things will help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Optional downcasting to `AppDelegate` (actually to the class representing the application delegate class) will never fail because the application won't even launch if the application delegate class was missing.

You can 100% safely write

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

---

Many people suffer from *exclamationmarkophobia*  and argue that all exclamation marks are evil and you **always** have to `guard` any optional. This is wrong. The world is not only black and white. There are many cases where forced unwrapping an optional is safe like in this particular case.

Comment: Thank you so much Vadian. This is extremely helpful, believe me. I often avoid using force unwrapping as well, but its good to know that it is safe to use now and again.

Comment: As of 2019, it's not phobia anymore, they banned it with error : Force Cast Violation: Force casts should be avoided. (force_cast)

Comment: @Async- Who is *they* and where does this error occur?

Comment: @vadian yeah sorry, it was actually SwiftLint in my case, I confused it with xcode error.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the `@UIApplicationMain` attribute to a class

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { ... }
```

is *equivalent* to calling `UIApplicationMain()` in "main.swift"
with "AppDelegate" as the name of the class from which the application delegate is instantiated:

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory(
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    nil,
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

(compare e.g. [What does "@UIApplicationMain" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean/24596759) and [Subclass UIApplication with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift)).

With either method, an instance of the `AppDelegate` class is created
and passed as delegate to the application object. So yes,

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

is safe.

But note that there is nothing special about the class name "AppDelegate", this is just convention. You can define the application
delegate as

```
@UIApplicationMain
class MyFantasticAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { ... }
```

in which case it of course would be

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! MyFantasticAppDelegate
```

So the precise statement would be

> Casting `UIApplication.shared.delegate` to the type of the class defined as application delegate cannot fail.

By convention, that type is `AppDelegate`, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll read those two links - this is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I can't agree with the point that force unwrapping downcasting to AppDelegate will never fail. It's isn't true. Because 'AppDelegate' could be the wrong type for your delegate. For example, I faced it when app used RxAppState framework. It has an extension for AppDelegate which returns 'RxAppState.RxApplicationDelegateProxy' class as the delegate. So always be careful.

Comment: Yes, but this is a **design** mistake which can be fixed immediately.