# What is difference between UIApplicationMain and UIApplication

Tags: ios, uiapplication

As I know `UIApplicationMain` will execute as the user will tap on app icon by the system and it will run all loops and app infrastructure.

But I don't know when and who calls `UIApplication`

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516250/what-does-uiapplicationmain-mean

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the two? After doing so, please [edit] your question with details about what you are unclear about.