# Xcode fresh MacOS project shows compile errors like Use of "Undeclared type NSObject"

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I'm facing a few problems with Xcode. I have searched around and nothing helps... to make things worst i'm learning everything from scratch. swift, xcode, build mac apps... coming from ruby/rails this is extremely painful!

A while ago all projects started throwing errors like the use of undeclared type 'NSObject' and so on.

I am using Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d).

The project still runs if I clean/build it and run. But as soon as I select another file and come back the AppDelegate the errors appear again. Also cmd+clicking just displays "Symbol not found" and autocompletion doesn't work.

I created a new blank project (multiple times) and this still happens. I didn't even touch the code! I have attached two images to show my problems.

[image]

The first line error I managed to fix it following [Subclass UIApplication with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift/24021180#24021180):

Basically I removed `@NSApplicationMain` from AppDelegate and created a main.swift file with these lines.

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

NSApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV)
```

this seems to fix the 'NSApplicationMain' class must conform to the 'NSApplicationDelegate' protocol error.

But I can't see how to fix the other errors. Any help please? :) Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: try cleaning your DerivedData folder

Comment: Cleaning DerivedData did not help!