# Xcode 8 beta 6: main.swift won't compile

Tags: swift, xcode, program-entry-point, swift3, xcode8-beta6

We have a custom UIApplication object, so our main.swift was

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, NSStringFromClass(MobileUIApplication), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

and that didn't work in Xcode 8 beta 5 so we used this

```
//TODO Swift 3 workaround? https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46405
UIApplicationMain( Process.argc, UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>>(Process.unsafeArgv), nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

On Xcode 8 beta 6 we get **Use of unresolved identifier 'Process'**

What do we need to do in Xcode 8 beta 6/Swift 3 to define the UIApplicationMain?

Comment: How do I specify the UIApplication class that way?

Comment: Looks like this problem is finally fixed in iOS 12 Xcode 10.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I write it this way:

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory(
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    nil,
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

To change the UIApplication class, substitute `NSStringFromClass(MobileUIApplication.self)` for `nil` in that formulation.

However, if your *only* purpose here is to substitute a UIApplication subclass as the shared application instance, there's an easier way: in the *Info.plist*, add the "Principal class" key and set its value to the string name of your UIApplication subclass, and mark your declaration of that subclass with an `@objc(...)` attribute giving it the same Objective-C name.

**EDIT** This problem is now solved in Swift 4.2. `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` now has the correct signature, and one can call `UIApplicationMain` easily:

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, 
    nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Comment: "CommandLine.unsafeArgv now has the correct signature" might be misleading, it has the same signature as in older Swift versions. The signature of UIApplicationMain changed, and the argv parameter now matches CommandLine.unsafeArgv. – Anyway, it is nice that this has been fixed.

Comment: I'm getting this warning: `'UIApplicationMain' is deprecated: Use the overload of UIApplicationMain where the type of the second parameter is UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>, which is the same as the type of CommandLine.unsafeArgv.`

Answer (score 5):

It seems `Process` has been renamed to `CommandLine` in beta 6.

[CommandLine](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/commandline)

But the type of `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` is mismatching the second argument of `UIApplication`, so you may need to write something like this:

```
CommandLine.unsafeArgv.withMemoryRebound(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)) {argv in
    _ = UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, argv, NSStringFromClass(MobileUIApplication.self), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
}
```

(UPDATE)This mismatching should be considered as a bug. Generally, you'd better send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) when you find "this-should-not-be" things, like the third parameter in beta 5. I hope this "bug" will be fixed soon.

---

If you just want to designate your custom UIApplication class, why don't you use Info.plist?

```
NSPrincipalClass | String | $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).MobileUIApplication
```

(Shown as "Principal class" in non-Raw Keys/Values view.)

With this in your Info.plist, you can use your `MobileUIApplication` with normal way using `@UIApplicationMain`.

(ADDITION) Header doc of `UIApplicationMain`:

> ```
> // If nil is specified for principalClassName, the value for NSPrincipalClass from the Info.plist is used. If there is no
> // NSPrincipalClass key specified, the UIApplication class is used. The delegate class will be instantiated using init.
> ```

Comment: Please note that this situation is regarded as a bug. This answer is more or less identical to the one given here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1390?focusedCommentId=17441&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17441

Comment: @matt , I don't think telling `Process` is renamed to `CommandLine` is not identical to bug report. But, yes, seemingly the main code in my answer is showing a workaround for the bug, and I'll update the part.

Comment: @OOPer @matt I was able to use `NSPrincipleClass` in the Info.plist for an iOS app. But as far as I can tell it is not documented. This approach works better for my project.

Comment: @Brad, it's documented in the header doc. Cmd-click on `UIApplicationMain`. As far as I know, iOS 8 SDK has the description about this and with all combination of iOS versions (8+) and simulators and devices I have tested (not much, though), it works fine.

Comment: @OOPer Finally figured this out. In Swift, it's crucial to mark the UIApplication subclass declaration with `@objc(...)` to give it an unmunged Objective-C name. Then NSPrincipalClass works.

Comment: @matt, thanks for reporting. Unfortunately, my testing code does not have `@objc` attribute on the `UIApplication` subclass, but it worked. So, it does not explain all aspects of using `NSPrincipalClass`. But, it may be the safer way as you say you could have made it work.

Comment: @OOPer Perhaps sometimes the name gets munged and other times it doesn't. But in my new tests, it we use `@objc(...)` with a name, like `@objc(MyApplication) class MyApplication`, it always works.

Comment: @matt, that may happen. A minor 0.0.1 version up, or any other things may affect. As for now, we need to expect your _always_ would apply to our apps always.