# UnsafeMutablePointer to expected argument type UnsafeMutablePointer<_> in Swift 3

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift3, receigen

In the `main.swift` file, we have a call to our receipt checking system (generated by [Receigen](http://receigen.etiemble.com/guides-swift.html)). In Swift 2, `main.swift` read:

```
startup(Process.argc, UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>(Process.unsafeArgv))
```

After upgrading to Swift 3, I've got as far as:

```
startup(CommandLine.argc, UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>(CommandLine.unsafeArgv))
```

which shows the error:

> Cannot convert value of type
>   `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>` (aka
>   `UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>`) to
>   expected argument type `UnsafeMutablePointer<_>`

Update: Using the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39089634/341994) so that it reads:

```
startup(CommandLine.argc, UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
    .bindMemory(
        to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
        capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)))
```

Produces:

> Cannot convert value of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.Type` to
>   expected argument type `UnsafePointer<Int8>?.Type` (aka
>   `Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>.Type`)

Where the compiler is referring to the `to:UnsafeMutablePointer`.

The header for startup looks like:

```
int startup(int argc, const char * argv[]);
```

How can I successfully pass the variables to startup in `main.swift`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39089634/341994

Comment: I tried that before I wrote the question (honest!) but I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, but if you "tried that", where is your UnsafeMutableRawPointer? I don't see it.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Right but are you not now failing to take the `const` into account? `const` means _not_ mutable.

Comment: You may have just uncovered my inexperience with bridging between Swift & C - and hopefully the answer?

Comment: Right. UIApplicationMain expects a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>`. Your call expects you to pass a `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>?>`. So the difference would be that you need to say `Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>.self` as your `to:` type. Now, whether that will run correctly is a total mystery to me, but at least it will compile! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, this is a variant on the problem discussed here:

[Xcode 8 beta 6: main.swift won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088928/xcode-8-beta-6-main-swift-wont-compile)

The problem is that you have an impedance mismatch between the type of `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` and the type expected by your C function. And you can no longer cast away this mismatch merely by coercing from one mutable pointer type to another. Instead, you have to pivot (as it were) from one type to another by calling `bindMemory`. And the error message, demanding a `Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>.Type`, tells you what type to pivot to:

```
    startup(
        CommandLine.argc,
        UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
            .bindMemory(
                to: Optional<UnsafePointer<Int8>>.self,
                capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))
    )
```

That should allow you to compile. Testing on my machine with a stub of `startup`, it actually runs. But whether it will run on your machine, and whether it is safe, is anybody's guess! This stuff is undeniably maddening...

**EDIT** The problem with `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` is fixed in iOS 12 / Xcode 10, so it may be that this problem is fixed too.

Comment: Thankyou - I know it seems obvious but it's way out of my experience. When you say maddening, are you speaking from a testing / QA perspective?

Comment: I'm speaking from an "I can't wrap my mind around this and I don't see why I'm being forced to do it" perspective. :) The fact is that you've been given a crappy API to grapple with, and now you're stuck, grappling... You should complain to the Receigen people.

Comment: Seriously, when its easier to do something in base c than with swift api why even have these api's in swift?