# how to convert UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?> to UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>!

Tags: swift4, uiapplication

I am using swift 4.0 to re-write main.swift of my iOS application.
And this is my main.swift:

```
UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc,
              CommandLine.unsafeArgv
              NSStringFromClass(MyAPP.self),
              NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

there's an compile error here:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>!'
```

AnyOne know how to convert `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>!` here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 beta 6: main.swift won't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088928/xcode-8-beta-6-main-swift-wont-compile)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please check :

```
UIApplicationMain(  
    CommandLine.argc,  
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)  
        .bindMemory(  
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,  
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)
        ),  
    NSStringFromClass(MyAPP.self),  
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)  
)
```

Comment: this is a deprecated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutablePointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv),
    NSStringFromClass(MyAPP.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Comment: Consider adding some description why your code solves the problem.

Comment: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv) is deprecated.