# Converting main.m to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am converting my obj-c app to Swift. For the purpose of overriding system language preferences I am setting my locale in main.m. Something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    [defaults setObject:@"myweirdlocale" forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This needs to happen early, before any UIKit method is used. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate is too late. Since there is no main function in Swift. Is there a chance of doing this in Swift?

Comment: This might be a better reference: [Subclass UIApplication with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift). It shows how to replace `@UIApplicationMain` by an explicit `main` function in Swift.

Comment: Thanks. I just found it too. I like it better.