# Could not cast value of type 'UIApplication' to AutoLogoutUIApplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, casting, uiapplication

When I cast UIApplication.shareApplication() to my custom class AutoLogoutUIApplication, I got an error like below when I use Swift.

> Could not cast value of type 'UIApplication' (0x28f4408) to 'Porject_Name.AutoLogOutUIApplication' (0x1f50d0).

Here is my code in swift:

```
let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication() as! AutoLogOutUIApplication
app.enableAutoLogout = false
```

In objective-c :

```
((AutoLogOutUIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication]).enableAutoLogout = NO;
```

Here is my AutoLogOutUIApplication class:

```
class AutoLogOutUIApplication: UIApplication {
   //properties
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Your shared application isn't an instance of `AutoLogoutUIApplication`.  Have you removed the `@UIApplicationMain` line from your app delegate and added a new `main.swift` file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift

Comment: @Paulw11 can you show me by example with coding?

Comment: Refer to the question I linked to