# How catch a button's touch event by setting a breakpoint?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got an old project and tried to find out where is code responding the button's touch event.

I wandering if there is anyway to catch my touch on a button and break at the selector method or somewhere related like when you make a symbolic breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the event sending in UIApplication: `- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

see:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621614-sendevent?language=swift
- [Subclass UIApplication with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020000/subclass-uiapplication-with-swift/24021180) (on SO)

by overriding that method you can get any event sent to your app and you can intercept any touch event