# iOS Localization of Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, localization, settings, bundle

I have localised the setting bundle with different language and it works as expected the problem is when the device language is changed for example to French- Canada  my settings bundle is updated to FR-CA automatically as my app supports. But if the device language is set to some other unsupported language like Chinese then the settings bundle stay back in Fr-CA where i need it to be in Default English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default localization of iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460202/set-default-localization-of-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do this as the OS choose the language from the prefered languages array in your settings . You have to  manually re order to get it done. Apple has clearly mentioned on their website. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1828/_index.html